# How do I know css transition animation is ended?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set `animating = false` once the transition animation is ended, I used settimeout , it works ok on desktop but the timing is wrong on ipad, Is it possible to know the css animation of an object ended exactly?

CSS:

```
#pane{ -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-out ; }
```

JavaScript:

```
function css_translate(j, k) {
    var i = 'translate(' + k + 'px,0px)';
    j.css({
        'transform': i,
        '-moz-transform': i,
        '-webkit-transform': i,
        '-o-transform': i,
    });
}
if (animating == false) {
    animating = true;
    css_translate($pane, handler.page[handler.currentp + 1] * -1);
}
setTimeout(function() {
    handler.animating = false;
}, transitiontime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end of the CSS transition [triggers a `transitionEnd` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-events), so you can know exactly.  These events are using the vendor prefixes, so you need to deal with that ... for Chrome/Webkit, it's `webkitTransitionEnd`:

```
j.on('webkitTransitionEnd', function(event) {
    handler.animating = false;
});
```

[Obligatory JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ET3Vz/4/)